# Different output at each run?

Tags: c++

After I'm compiling the code

```
#include <iostream>

int* func(int a) { return &a; }

int main() {
std::cout << func(2) << std::endl;
}
```

when I run the executable multiple times, it returns different values at each run. This confuses me, I would have expected that the compiler removes all variable names and replaces them with fixed memory addresses, and therefore at each run of the executable I should have obtained the same value ?

Comment: Your understanding of compilation is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) for one possible reason that the `a` variable gets stored at a different address each run.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you run your program OS allocate to it different parts of memory.

So do not expect each time you will have same memory address for same variable.

[Operating System - Memory Management](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_memory_management.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the hint - could you be a bit more specific though, please ? Are you referring to heap vs. stack ? What exactly is allocated where at each run, that makes it take different values ?

Comment: @user7088945 I have added prof link. There you can how OS place new process into the memory

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that you would get a warning about this from both `gcc` and `clang`.  You don't even have to pass any warning flags to be told about the mistake:

**clang++:**

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'a' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
int* func(int a) { return &a; }
```

**g++:**

```
warning: address of local variable ‘a’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 int* func(int a) { return &a; }
```